Salesforce Omniscript Not Refreshing when Values are Updated
We have an Omniscript that takes text input from the user- name and email. There is a Data Mapper Extract Action that then checks if name and email exactly matches a record in Salesforce, it will throw a duplicate error message. However, when the user edits the last name and tries to resubmit, it will still throw the error even though the name has changed and doesn't match a record in salesforce. In other words, even though the text input has changed, the data mapper extract is still using the original values to call the error.
Has anyone experienced this/ has a work around?
I am expecting the data mapper extract to refresh with the edited values.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
